# JavaScript & CSS Accordion List

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have code for an accordion list using CSS and JavaScript. When I click on a heading it brings up the hidden content. How do I make this so if I click on the same heading it will hide the content again? Anything helps, cheers.

```js
(function () {
  var accordions, i;
  
  // Make sure the browser supports what we are about to do.
  if (!document.querySelectorAll || !document.body.classList) return;
  
  // Using a function helps isolate each accordion from the others
  function makeAccordion(accordion) {
    var targets, currentTarget, i;
    
    targets = accordion.querySelectorAll('.accordion > * >h1 ');
    for(i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
      targets[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (currentTarget)
          currentTarget.classList.remove('expanded');
        
        currentTarget = this.parentNode;
        currentTarget.classList.add('expanded');
      }, false);
    }

    accordion.classList.add('js');
  }

  // Find all the accordions to enable
  accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
  
  // Array functions don't apply well to NodeLists
  for(i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
    makeAccordion(accordions[i]);
  }
  
})();
```

```css
<style>
.accordion.js > * {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion.js > *:not(.expanded) > *:not(h1) {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.accordion.js > .expanded > *:not(h1) {
  max-height: 10em;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.accordion.js > * > h1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}

.accordion.js > * > *:not(h1) {
  transition: max-height 0.7s,
    visibility 1s,
    margin 1s,
    opacity 1s;
}

.sections {
color:#5E5E5E;
text-align:center;
width:90%;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#D1D1D1;
padding: 0 .5em;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-radius:3px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<section class="accordion">
  <section class="sections">
    <h1>A</h1>
    <p>All content for A.</p>
  </section>
  <br style="line-height:5px"/>
  <section class="sections">
    <h1>B</h1>
    <p>All content for B</p>
  </section>
  <br style="line-height:5px"/>
  <section class="sections">
    <h1>C</h1>
    <p>All content for C<p>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

All I did was add a condition to check if the accordion class exits on the target parent and remove it if it does. Otherwise everything else is the same.

```js
(function () {
  var accordions, i;
  
  // Make sure the browser supports what we are about to do.
  if (!document.querySelectorAll || !document.body.classList) return;
  
  // Using a function helps isolate each accordion from the others
  function makeAccordion(accordion) {
    var targets, currentTarget, i;
    targets = accordion.querySelectorAll('.accordion > * >h1 ');
    for(i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
      targets[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      /*Added the code below*/
        if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains("expanded")) {
          e.target.parentNode.classList.remove("expanded")
        } else {
        /*Else do the following, same as before */
        if (currentTarget) 
          currentTarget.classList.remove('expanded');
        
        currentTarget = this.parentNode;
        currentTarget.classList.add('expanded');
        }
      }, false);
    }

    accordion.classList.add('js');
  }

  // Find all the accordions to enable
  accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
  console.log(accordions);
  
  // Array functions don't apply well to NodeLists
  for(i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
    makeAccordion(accordions[i]);
  }
  
})();
```

```css
.accordion.js > * {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion.js > *:not(.expanded) > *:not(h1) {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.accordion.js > .expanded > *:not(h1) {
  max-height: 10em;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.accordion.js > * > h1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}

.accordion.js > * > *:not(h1) {
  transition: max-height 0.7s,
    visibility 1s,
    margin 1s,
    opacity 1s;
}

.sections {
color:#5E5E5E;
text-align:center;
width:90%;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#D1D1D1;
padding: 0 .5em;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<section class="accordion">
  <section class="sections">
    <h1>A</h1>
    <p>All content for A.</p>
  </section>
  <br style="line-height:5px"/>
  <section class="sections">
    <h1>B</h1>
    <p>All content for B</p>
  </section>
  <br style="line-height:5px"/>
  <section class="sections">
    <h1>C</h1>
    <p>All content for C<p>
  </section>
</section>
```